# how to annotate an equation in the align environment

Tags: align

I have a bunch of equations in an `begin{align}` environment that are centered on the page. The left hand side has a fair bit of white space and i would like to put some text there to annotate/describe the equation. See attached picture

[image]

I would try to avoid `tag` if possible because i need the equation numbers.

Comment: Do the annotations have to be rotated ninety degrees? (Most people hate to have to crane their necks to read something...)

Comment: No, it's a bad picture.. I basically want `(Equation 1)  S' = f(x)  A`, (Equation 2)  Z'  = g(x) A2` Simple annotation per equation, regular orientation

Comment: How would this benefit the reader if you add "Equation ..."   left of all equations and also have an equation number on the right margin?

Comment: It's not just "euqation" I would like to add a description of the equation like "susceptibles", "infected", "hospitalized" and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be useful to add the text in mboxes that are aligned to the left of the equations?  Something like:

```
\begin{align}
\mbox{First comment}&~ & a+b&=c\\
\mbox{Another}&~ & d+e&=f\\
\mbox{And another}&~ & g+h&=i\\
\end{align}
```

that would produce
[image]

Comment: You may want to left align the comments by putting the `&` before the text. Also you should get rid of the last double backslash to avoid an additional line number. Lastly, the `\text` command is an option instead of `\mbox`. So something like this: `& \text{First comment} & a+b &=c`